# Show list of users based on taxonomy term (D7)

Tags: drupal-7, view, taxonomy

I have a taxonomy vocabulary "Department". In the user account I have a taxonomy term reference field with this vocabulary. So each user can be assigned to one or more departments.
I used the module Taxonomy Meny to show the taxonomy terms in my main menu.

Now I want to show a list of users when I click on a department in the menu.
Does anybody have an idea how I could do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure here, but I suppose you should be able to use the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to achieve this. Use can show all user nodes (or a list by choosing fields) and enter the department as a contextual filter.

Uou can use views in 2 ways, to produce pages or blocks. Contextual filters are a bit easier with pages, but that might confilt with yout module.

I like this tutorial, it gives a clear insight in contextual filters. It should get you started.
http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/using-drupal-contextual-filters-views